# Swift 5 clickable Label open maps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I am learning iOS development. I have create UILable which display the Gps coordinates of user. as below

```
func locationManager(_ _manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations Location:[CLLocation]){
    if let location = Location.first{
        coordinate.text = "Your location \(location.coordinate.latitude.description) \(location.coordinate.longitude.description) - \(location.timestamp.description)"
        speed.text = "Your moving at speed of \(location.speed.description) course \(location.courseAccuracy.description)"
        altitude.text = "Your at altitude of \(location.altitude.description)"
```

I have Label which I name coordinate that display the current Gps coordinate and it's clickable as below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var coordinate: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    coordinate.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.labelAction(_:)))
    coordinate.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    coordinate.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func labelAction(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Coordinate", message: "I have been clicked...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    debugPrint("clicked")
}
```

Now whats happening is when you click coordinate:UILabel its show the alert message. But what I Wan't is to open the map app and point to current Gps coordinate. I have been able to achieve this but not with click of label but when the app launch. Below is the sample Example of what I have achieved.

```
   func locationManager(_ _manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations Location:[CLLocation]){
        if let location = Location.first{
            coordinate.text = "Your location \(location.coordinate.latitude.description) \(location.coordinate.longitude.description) - \(location.timestamp.description)"
            speed.text = "Your moving at speed of \(location.speed.description) course \(location.courseAccuracy.description)"
            altitude.text = "Your at altitude of \(location.altitude.description)"
            
//            let object  =  CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
//            print(object.description)

            let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000
            let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
            let regionSpant = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, latitudinalMeters: regionDistance, longitudinalMeters: regionDistance)
            let option = [
                MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey:NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpant.center),
                MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey:NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpant.span)
            ]
            let placeMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placeMark)
            mapItem.name = "You are Here"
            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: option)

            
        }
        
    }
```

what I want is to move the part below

```
 let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000
            let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
            let regionSpant = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, latitudinalMeters: regionDistance, longitudinalMeters: regionDistance)
            let option = [
                MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey:NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpant.center),
                MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey:NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpant.span)
            ]
            let placeMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placeMark)
            mapItem.name = "You are Here"
            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: option)
```

To move it to `@objc func labelAction(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)` so I will be able to open a map only when I click the label.But what am struggling with is to get `CLLocationCoordinate` out of `locationManger` function and pass it to `labelAction` function any suggestion or help I would appreciate. I apologies for my English I am using google translator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance variable

```
var lastCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate?
```

And assign it here

```
func locationManager(_ _manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]){
    if let location = locations.first {
        lastCoordinate = location.coordinate
        ....
```

Then use it anywhere

```
@objc func labelAction(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
   guard let coor = lastCoordinate else { return }
   // use coor
```